# close modal dialog in sandbox solutions

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, modal-dialog

i tried to close the modal dialog in sandbox solution using the following code

```
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
```

but its throwing null value error at

**context.Response.End();**

this works fine in farm solutions but not work sandbox solution.

is there any way to close modal dialog in sandbox solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you call this code from?

Comment: i calling this code from server side of modal popup page

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following code,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegistrerClientScriptBlock(this.getType(), "script", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, someValue");
```

Or use a script manager in your page and try with the following code,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">                SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 'Submitted');     </script>", true);
```

Comment: i tried with this code, but not works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">window.parent.close();</script>");
this.Response.Flush();
```

It always works for me.

Comment: i tried with this code, but not works

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your redirect code isn't working and it raises `Null Exception` may be because your WebPart is a Sandboxed solution.

For redirect in SandBoxed solutions you can try the following:

1. Create a `Literal` control.
2. In your code-behind, add similar code as this one:

   ```
   literalRedirect.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('" + redirectUrl + "');</script>"; //where /(redirectUrl) is a String variable.
   ```

Source: [here.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/handling-page-redirection-in-sharepoint-sandboxed-solutions/)